# Order of events with jquery

Tags: jquery, click, focusout

I have the following situation:

Textbox where you can type a keyword. The keyup event triggers an AJAX script which looks in the database for similar keywords. When found a DIV will be visible (`show()`) with the found keywords.

When clicking on one of the keywords in the div the selected keyword will be written in the textbox and the div will be hidden (`hide()`).

But when the DIV is visible and I click somewhere else in the form or I tab out of the textbox (the focusout event) I would like the DIV to be hidden.

This could be done with the focusout event. But when I use the click event for registering the click on a keyword in the DIV and using the focusout event for registering the focusout event the following problem occurs: When clicking the keyword in the div the focusout event will be triggered so my DIV will be hidden but the keyword will not be copied to the textbox.

I currently have the following code:

```
/*click on found "link with class f_link" in DIV*/
$(".f_link").live('click', function(){

    $newval=$(this).attr("id");
    $("#textbox_id").val($newval);
    $("#searchresults").hide();
})


/*when losing focus textbox hide DIV */
$("#textbox_id").focusout(function(){
    $("#searchresults").hide();

})
```

explaination:

```
#textbox_id : id of textbox
#searchresults: id of DIV with found results
.f_link : class of "link" in div searchresults like <span class="f_link" id="result1>result 1</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/*when losing focus textbox hide DIV */
$("#textbox_id").blur(function(){
    $("#searchresults").hide();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Blur didn't work (focusout is an event in jquery as well..)

I managed it with this solution:

```
$(".f_link").live('click', function(){
    $("#textbox_id").val($newval=$(this).attr("id"));
    $("#searchresults").hide();
})

$mouseover=false;
$("#searchresults").live('mouseover', function(){
    $mouseover=true;
})

$("#searchresults").live('mouseout', function(){
    $("#textbox_id").focus();
    $mouseover=false;
})



$("#textbox_id").focusout(function(){
    if ($mouseover) {
        return;
    }
    $("#searchresults").hide();
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use blur function istead of focusout...

```
$("#textbox_id").live('blur',function(){
     $("#searchresults").hide();
})
```